# How many ways can we put 2n white and n black balls into 3n different cells?

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

There are 3n different cells, 2n white balls, and n black balls.

Each cell cannot be empty and must contain exactly one ball. How many ways can we put those balls into those cells?

My solution is:

Let's start with putting all the 2n white balls in the cells $\binom{3n}{n}$.

than I have n cells and n black balls $\binom{n}{n}$.

we get: $\binom{3n}{n}$ * $\binom{n}{n}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your header refers to "$2n+n$ *different* balls", which suggests that the balls can be distinguished.  If you meant that the balls were indistinguishable apart from color, then yes.  Your expression is correct though I think it would be clearer if you wrote it as $\binom {3n}{2n}\times \binom nn = \binom {3n}{2n}$.

Comment: There is no difference between one white ball and another white ball (the same goes for blacks). Of course there is a difference between blacks and whites.
Section B of the question is a little harder for me. how many ways can we put the 2n white balls and n black balls in 3n different cells, but this time every cells can contain at most 1 white ball.

Comment: Then you should edit your post so that the header does not refer to "different" balls.    As to the variant:  Not sure it is well phrased. Is there no condition on the placement of the black balls.  They could all go into one cell along with a white ball?

Comment: @lulu. yes, u can put all the black balls in one cell and that the others cell will remain empty. u can put 1 white ball in cell number 1, and let all the other cells remain empty.

Comment: So...you don't need to place all the balls in the urns?  I feel like I'm just guessing at the rules here.  I suggest posting a new question in which you write out all the rules clearly and completely.